# Bitlocker не может зашифровать папку steam

Tags: windows-10, шифрование, steam, диск

Я хотел зашифровать съёмный Ж/Д. Запустил BitLocker. Он дошёл до 36.5% и завис. Я его перезапустил и теперь он расшифровывает диск обратно (решил сделать так, пока не поздно). Открыл флешку и там файлы были переименованы и переведены в странный формат (наверно, это значит, что они правильно зашифровались). Но папка steam (размером около 14гб) оказалась не зашифрована. И ещё 1 небольшая папка тоже, но это скорее шифровальщик до неё просто не дошёл. Steam с диска запущен не был, на пк был, но тот что на пк - установлен на диске D. Как это можно исправить?